# Linux mint Tara 19 problems with Nvidia Drivers [MX150]

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, gpu

I am trying to get my system to use my Nvidia MX150 graphics card.

Problem:

### Nvidia X Server settings shows a blank screen.

[image]

The driver manager shows that i'm using nvidia-driver-390
and also says "No proprietary drivers are in use"

[image]

What I've tried:

1. `sudo apt purge nvidia*`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt upgrade`
4. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

The output of `inxi -G` shows:

```
Card-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620
Card-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX150]
        Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: modesetting,nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
        Resolution: 1920x1080@59.98hz
        OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5
```

What steps can I take to fix the issue at hand?

Comment: Is pressing the "Apply Changes" button out of question?

Comment: It's greyed out implying it's already in use i'm assuming

Comment: @Martijn.Z What happens if you click on any other option and then back on `nvidia-driver-390`, is now still the Apply button greyed out?

Comment: @Martijn.Z Also, you do not mention in your question that you already use an Nvidia drivers PPA, which becomes obvious from the picture. Please take your time and improve on your question contents. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem on **Linux Mint 19.2** with **Nvidia MX150**.
Here is how I have managed to make it work:

1. Uninstall all of the nvidia related packages

```
sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

2. Verify that all of the nvidia related packages have been removed

```
sudo apt list | grep nvidia
```

3. Remove the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` repository entry

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

4. Reboot (optionally disable the secure boot in BIOS)
5. Install the latest recommended nvidia driver using Driver Manager
   [image: nvidia-driver-435 distro non-free recommended]
6. Reboot and check if the GPU is visible in the Nvidia X Server Settings or in the output of the `nvidia-smi` command. Also check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074692/563566) if you cannot see the details of the MX150 in the X Server or in the `nvidia-smi` command output.

---

Hardware:
Lenovo T480 with Nvidia MX150

Comment: Also, why don't you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: No. It is the latest driver version listed (as of writting this comment) when I use the `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-` [tab] command

Comment: please post the output of `apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-440`, as I have the very same OS, and I don't see it in the official repository.

Comment: I have added the output of the `apt-cache ...` command. I had to run the commands from the 2nd point to have the version 440 listed.

Comment: Alright, so it comes from that PPA. Now, could you confirm if version 435 would really not do the trick, for the users not to be forced to use a PPA.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, ok, I will try it.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, unfortunately it seems not to be working with the non-ppa nvidia-driver-435. The GPU is not visible in the Nvidia X Server Settings. `nvidia-smi` command outputs: "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

Comment: Ok, now, may I suggest using an Ubuntu package with: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-435=435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`, please?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, I have uninstalled the driver (`sudo apt-get remove nvidia*`). Used the suggested command to install the specific version. I had to also install `nvidia-settings`. The result is the same: (X Server Settings do not have the GPU listed, `nvidia-smi` command outputs "NVIDIA-SMI has failed (...)". I will try to install the ppa's 440 version again.

Comment: At this moment even the installation of the 440 (ppa) version fails. I am going to remove the answer as the steps seem to be insufficient to install the drivers properly

Comment: I agree, but remember you can undelete once you get it working.